# Changing emacs terminal color theme

Tags: emacs

This might be dumb question but I'm a newbie and having a lot of trouble changing my emacs color scheme. I think i already changed colors for my desktop version of emacs, but whenever i open .c files from terminal, they turn up just plain black and white? 
Anyways, 
I really want to download the monokai color scheme but I'm really confused on the directions for installation. Would someone mind helping me through with it?

https://github.com/oneKelvinSmith/monokai-emacs

it says to

"Download monokai-theme.el to the directory ~/.emacs.d/themes/. Add this to your .emacs:"

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
```

How do i download something through emacs? I know it has something to do with adding stuff to the .emacs file...but do i just put it anywhere in there? I know theres already lines in there and I don't want to mess any of that up.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't download through emacs, just use a web browser. If you want to do the emacs way, use the second installation apporach

Answer (score 1):

1)Open github.com/oneKelvinSmith/monokai-emacs

2)You have a green button (up right) "clone or download " to download monokai-theme.

3)After downloading, unzip monokai-emacs-master.zip

4)If necessary do : mkdir ~/.emacs.d/themes

5)cd monokai-emacs-master;cp monokai-theme.el ~/.emacs.d/themes/

6)add to your ~/.emacs : (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")

7)Inside emacs :M-x load-theme RET monokai   (of course RET is return)

Comment: thanks, but that just downloads the file? Am i supposed to copy that file in terminal?

Comment: @ipp refresh your screen

Comment: thanks, this was really helpful! i think it worked, although the theme is still not appearing when i do M-x customize-themes, do i have to edit my .emacs file for that?